# Challenging Excel VBA/Macro for inventory management

Tags: vba, excel

I work for an eCommerce company and we use Microsoft Excel for our inventory database. We currently just keep adding items to this database as we purchase them, without ever removing them. What I would like to do is start removing items as they sell. I am not sure how to attach the file, so if you e-mail me at drenollet@supplykick.com I can send it to you. Below are the following steps:

1. The Sales tab includes the sales data for the items. I would like to take this data and be able to copy and paste it in a sheet in our Inventory Managment file in excel (a separate file, but I included a sample in the "Database" sheet).
2. I then need to just use a VLOOKUP formula and the Catalog data to get the Product ID instead of the SKU. (I can do this.)
3. Then use the copied data in the Sales Tab that is in the Inventory Management file and move the corresponding rows out of the Database file/sheet to the Sold Items sheet.

A few thoughts on specifics:

I want to make sure all the quantities are right. (e.g.1 if we purchased two of an item and only one sold - reducing the quantity in the Database sheet from two down to one.) (e.g.2 If we purchased an item two different times at two different prices and both were purchased in one sale, I would want to make sure both of the rows are moved out of the database).

If you have any thoughts on making sure the quantities are right, let me know. Maybe we need to set all the purchase quantities to one and copy the purchase of a multiple quantity of items X number of times for each one that was purchased.

Would love your input on how to cross this bridge! Let me know if you would like to see the sample file and I can directly e-mail it to you!

Best Regards,
Don Renollet

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to have a sheet called Movements

then you have just rows of entries like

```
A        B              C     D
---------------------------------------- 
prodID   Movement type  Qty   Date
123      Purchase       5     08/01/15
789      Sale           2     07/01/15
123      Return         1     06/01/15
456      Sale           1     05/01/15
789      Purchase       10    04/01/15
456      Purchase       5     03/01/15
123      Sale           2     03/01/15
123      Return         1     02/01/15
123      Sale           1     02/01/15
123      Purchase       10    01/01/15
```

Then at anytime excel can calculate whats in stock using sumifs or similar

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,"123",B:B,"Purchase") - Sumif(C:C,A:A,"123",B:B,"Sale")) + Sumif(C:C,A:A,"123",B:B,"Return"))
```

You should never remove rows from a database like this, you can always do a stock take every so often and restart the database with 1 entry for each item, but aways store the old data elsewhere.

Try not to mix price with quantity if possible,  if you need to manage price , consider using a moving average price (MAP)